# Error: Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML` when injecting HTML into react component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to inject some HTML into a React component (Yes, it is clean) and I'm getting the error:

```
Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`
```

However I'm not sure how this applies to this code:

```
        <div className='pure-u-1' style={{ height: '300px' }}>
            <div className='blog-list-item-container' style={heroStyle}>
                <a as={`/post/${this.props.blogObject.slug}`} href={`/post?id=${this.props.blogObject.slug}`}>
                    <button className='blog-button' style={buttonStyle} />
                </a>
                <h1 className='pure-u-md-16-24 pure-u-sm-20-24 blog-list-title' ref={(titleElement) => this.titleElement = titleElement} style={{ marginTop: this.state.titleTop, height: this.state.titleHeight }}>{this.props.blogObject.title}</h1>
            </div>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(testLine)} /> 
        </div>
```

I'm only setting `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` one time.

The `createMarkup` function:

```
createMarkup(stringToConvertToHtml) {

    return { __html: stringToConvertToHtml }
}
```

The `testLine`:

```
const testLine = '<h3>All you need is X, Y, and center</h3><p>Every single visual element that you will use to build your application has coordinates built into it:</p>'
```

Comment: Where is "testLine" declared/initialized in your code?

Comment: @coffeeak It's a hard-coded `const` in `render()` for testing

Comment: can you post test line too and making the div a self-closing tag?

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. Just returning to this after a couple of days but it looks like I was forgetting to bind `createMarkup`.

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly unclear as to what the error is because I imagine it is in `createMarkup` call.  Make sure that your createMarkup is returning an object with the `__html` property and a string value of the proposed markup.  Also, try removing that space between your `div` tags.

```
createMarkup(testLine) {
 return { __html: '<div>your markup here</div>'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do that like this.

```
<div className={styles.activityContent} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.markDown( item.title ) }}>
```

And this is my function.

```
markDown(text){
if(text){
  //Here I replace special chars for html tags, this is the example: __ Text in bold __
  return text.replace(/__(.*?)__((_+|\W+|$))/g, '<strong>$1</strong>$2');
}
```

}